# htaccess rule <If> with fuzzy user agent

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've been trying for a while many combinations without success to achieve the following .htaccess rule:

```
    if user agent contains a specific string
```

then

```
    Do something
```

For example, say I'd like to redirect *any* Googlebot (image, etc.) to a specific page.

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Google
Redirect 301 /domain1/url/ https://domain1/url2
```

But it doesn't want to work.

I can achieve that for a specific UA, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'">
Redirect 301 /domain1/url/ https://domain1/url2
</If>
```

But that only works with `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)`. I couldn't find a clear answer in the documentation but it looks like `<If>` only accepts `==`.

How can I apply a regex rule in these conditions to match any user agent which include `Google` ?

Thank you!

Comment: _“but it looks like <If> only accepts ==”_ - you can aslo use regular expressions, and with  `-strmatch` also use patterns with some basic wildcards, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#binop

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like the Googlebot or bots at all, you should look into [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en)

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /nogooglebot/
```

In terms of .htaccess I have seen rules like that

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Google|bing).*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ "https\:\/\/yourdomain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

You can find a more complete blocklist [here](https://www.htmlremix.com/seo/block-google-and-bots-using-htaccess-and-robots-txt).